# not able to fetch using $and in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-stitch

I'm trying to use $and in mongodb stitch function to get data using 2 different condition

`data = col.find( { $and: [ { "title": { title } }, { "address.countryName": { country } } ] } ).toArray;`

but this shows $undefined:true in response.

please guide what is wrong in here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `{}` in the condition's value

```
db.getCollection('test').find({
  $and: [
    {
      "title": 'title' --> Here
    },
    {
      "address.countryName": 'country' --> Here
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: let me try with this

Comment: Let me know your sample data also if you face any problem.

Comment: hi tried with this ( { $and: [ { "title":title1 }, { "address.countryName":country } ] } )

my data set is : 
address:
address1:null
address2:null
city:"Miami"
state:"Arizona"
zip:null
countryID:1
countryName:"United States"
countryCode:"US",
"title":"United States"

but system is reuning 0 objects

Comment: Because you have no data with `title`. Please use `United States` in place of `title` value. And use proper country name from your document also